# Jenkins pipeline capture output of jenkins steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I archive (as a file) the console output of a jenkins pipeline step such as `docker.build(someTag)`?

Background:

I use jenkins pipelines to build a whole bunch of microservices.

I want to extract all the relevant information from the jenkins console into archived files, so that devs don't have to look at the console which confuses them. This works fine for `sh` steps were I can redirect stdout and stderr but how can I do something similar for a jenkins pipeline step?

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround we use following `LogRecorder` class:

```
class LogRecorder implements Serializable {
    def logStart
    def logEnd
    def currentBuild
    def steps

    LogRecorder(currentBuild) {
        this.currentBuild = currentBuild
    }

    void start() {
        logStart = currentBuild.getRawBuild().getLog(2000)
    }

    String stop() {
        logEnd = currentBuild.getRawBuild().getLog(2000)
        getLog()
    }

    String getLog() {
        def logDiff = logEnd - logStart
        return logDiff.join('\n')
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs you may want to adjust the number of log lines in the calls to `getLog()`.

Possible Usage:

```
LogRecorder logRecorder = new LogRecorder(currentBuild)
logRecorder.start()

docker.build(someTag)

testResult.stdOut = logRecorder.stop()
```

Please be aware that it may happen - most probably due to caching issues - that the very last line(s) of the log are sometimes missing. Maybe a sleep would help here. But so far this was not required here.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I'm using to capture the sha256 of the built docker image

```
docker.build(someTag)
def dockerSha256 = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "docker image inspect $someTag | jq .[0].Id").trim()
```

I'm using 'jq' to parse the json response

or the groovy way

```
    def json = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "docker image inspect $someTag").trim()
    def obj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

    println "raw json: " + obj
    println "groovy docker sha256: " + obj[0].Id
```